# Installing Malware Bytes from Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to create a script to install malware bytes through powershell silently. This is what I have got so far:

```
$down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url  = 'http://downloads.malwarebytes.org/file/mbam/mbam-setup-2.0.2.1012.exe';
$file = 'c:\Program Files\malwaresetup.exe';
$down.DownloadFile($url,$file);

c:\Program Files\malwaresetup.exe /install=agent /s;
```

This downloads and starts the install but then the user then has to at there end finish off the installation (Selecting language location etc) is there anyway of completely silently installing the software so the user doesn't have to do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `malwaresetup.exe /?`, you'll get list of accepted command line parameters. You can write:

`c:\Program Files\malwaresetup.exe /install=agent /verysilent`

for no GUI whatsoever, or:

`c:\Program Files\malwaresetup.exe /install=agent /silent /suppressmsgboxes`

for unattended GUI installation (showing progress bar).